# Is a WPF app using external dll but successfully desktop-bridged a promising candidate for Microsoft Store?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

My one `WPF` app is using an external `dll`. I tried to convert the app to `UWP` by using the same code of `WPF` but it did not workout since - as expected - the external dll did not work in `UWP`. However, when I [Desktop Bridged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-root) that `WPF` app to `UWP` it worked - and I can successfully deploy it on my various Windows 10 laptops using [App Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/) - and I've tested that this newly desktop bridged app work there fine . Is this desktop bridged app now a promising candidate for 'Microsoft Store`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the "external DLL" is included in the app package you submit to the Store this will be a valid candidate for the Microsoft Store.

Comment: I constantly find you MSFT people answering off topic questions here on SO and I wish you would stop it. Perhaps reading the Help Center or taking The Tour would have helped but I feel Microsoft has told you not to obey that directive.